# Is it necessary to match groups before running random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, survival, random-forest, propensity-scores

I' m doing a survival analysis using machine learning with random forest method.
 There are two groups for comparison.
But two groups are so unmatched in baseline characteristics.
I performed propensity score matching with 1:1 ratio which eliminated all inequalities(assess by ASMD plot). But my sample volume dropped to 30%.
2:1 ratio PSM was not satisfactory regarding to matching performance.
Is it necessary to match data groups before random forest?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from each group?